# unit circle in complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

In a complex plane, $z = e^{iθ}$ will form a unit circle. All the points on the circle will form a [circle group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_group) as well.

My question is if I change the original equation to the following forms, what will the corresponding plot be?

A: $z = 2e^{iθ}$
B: $z = e^{i2θ}$

I tried to plot it on the Wolframalpha website. However, I found it not supported.

Comment: A: will map to a circle of radius 2.  B: will map to the unit circle, but you go round twice as fast.  The set of $z$ that satisfies A does not form a group (at least not with the standard multiplication).  The set of $z$ that satisfies B does